# How to reliably detect touch devices in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I believe that EDGE recently changed its behaviour and when used on a Desktop, non touch device, now reports values > 0 for navigator.maxTouchPoints

This breaks the following JS-Code we use to detect touch-devices:

```
function is_touch_device() {
    var touch = false;
    if ( window.PointerEvent && ('maxTouchPoints' in navigator) ) {
        // if Pointer Events are supported, just check maxTouchPoints
        if (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) {
          touch = true;
        }
    } else {
        // no Pointer Events...
        if ( window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(any-pointer:coarse)").matches ) {
          // check for any-pointer:coarse which mostly means touchscreen
            touch = true;
        } else if ( window.TouchEvent || ('ontouchstart' in window) ) {
            // last resort - check for exposed touch events API / event handler
            touch = true;
        }
    }
    return touch;
}
```

Does anyone know of a reliable way to detect (in JS) if MS Edge is used on a touch device? I haven't been able to find anything.

I know Edge is almost dead, but for the time being, i have to support it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to check whether it is a touch device.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
        document.write("your device is a touch screen device.");
    }
    else {
        document.write("your device is NOT a touch device");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but did you see, that the code i currently use, which is quoted in my post does include this already and AFAIK MS doesn't support `ontochstart`at all. What do i misunderstand here?